# listview via soap call in android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, listadapter, android-ksoap2

Hi i have successfully developed one listview app..now i have to click any item from that list means the detail description is displayed on next activity...it is also successfully finished..now my output is below format:

```
1   F   Krishna
2   Q   Danesh
3   P   Mercy
```

here i have to click the **2 Q Danesh** item it is go to next activity.the next activity have to displayed

`Q  Danesh`

it is succssfully worked.

but now i wish to need the listview like this format:

```
1 Krishna
2 Danesh
3 Mercy
```

Here i have to click the **2 Danesh** means it is go to next activity and the next activity have to display

`Q`

how can i do....please help me...

the below code is my webservice code:

```
 public class RetailerWs {
 public String customerData1(){
 String customerInfo = "";
 try{
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xcart-432pro","root","");
```

//Find customer information where the customer ID is maximum
     PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM xcart_orders");
     ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

```
 while(result.next()){
   customerInfo = customerInfo 
            + result.getString("orderid") 
            + " "   // this to separate order id from status
            + result.getString("status") 
            + " " 
    // this to separate order id from status
            + result.getString("login") 
            + "&" ;
 //Here "&"s are added to the return string. This is help to split the string in Android application
}
}

catch(Exception exc){
System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
}

return customerInfo;
}

 }
```

this is my android code:

```
public class RetailerActivity extends Activity {
ListView list;
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/customerData1";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "customerData1";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8089/XcartLogin/services/RetailerWs?wsdl";
private static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
private static final String KEY_LOGIN = "login";


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        SoapPrimitive s = response;
        String str = s.toString();
        String resultArr[] = str.split("&");
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,resultArr));
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String status =  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                String[] status1  = status.split(" ");

                 String StrStatus = status1[1].toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_STATUS, StrStatus);

                startActivity(in);            



            }
        });     
    }


    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

  }
```

this is my next activity:

```
 public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// XML node keys
static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    String StrStatus = in.getStringExtra(KEY_STATUS);


    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_label);
    lblName.setText(StrStatus);

  }
  }
```

please help me....

Comment: it is possible or not possible...anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You can take your Q from List Screen to other Activity.

You just have to change in your first Activty (which is your Q Value)

```
in.putExtra("StrStatus", StrStatus);
```

and then you can get this in your other activity through

```
Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!=null) {
    STRStatus=extras.getString("StrStatus");
}
```

This will have your Q value and you can do whatever you want.

-----
BTW - Which error ure you getting?
You can use this to Click your List Item

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent,View v,int position,long id){
try {
    TextView t4=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.No);

    if (t4!=null){
        BeanClass/*ClassName*/  mSelected;
        int idx=position;
        mSelected=m_adapter.getItem(idx);           
        String ActionID=mSelected.getID();

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,SoneActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("StrStatus", StrStatus);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not worked for me...please read my update question and give me solution for this...

Comment: @user1676640  was  that a Request  or Order...?

Comment: any idea about how is implement this...if you know means help me please

Comment: yeaa sure i would love to help you
 why dont u use Constructor

 public void onListItemClick(ListView parent,View v,int position,long id){
}

Comment: i got below error on this(list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {) line:The type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, 
 long)